# overriding backbone js sync method to add xhr event listener

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js

```
sync: function(method,model,options){

        options.beforeSend = function(xhr,settings) {

            settings.xhr = function() {  
                console.log('test');

            }

        }


        return Backbone.sync(method,model,options);
    }
```

I would like to implement a progress bar for my model fetch, and have added the code above to override the sync to access the xhr method. However, it doesn't seem to fire or do anything. I'm using jquery 2.0.3 and backbone 1.1.2

EDIT:

The problem I have now is that updateProgress only fire once at the end.

```
options.beforeSend = function(xhr,settings) {

            settings.xhr = function() {  
                var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();

                xhr.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);



                function updateProgress(event){
                    console.log('loaded:'+event.loaded+' total:'+event.total);
                    Math.ceil(event.loaded/event.total*100);
                }



                return xhr;

            };


         }
```

Comment: Are you sure? It seems to work and log `test` on the console. http://jsbin.com/yegusirusu/1/edit?js,console Did you add proper "url" property to your class?

Comment: Ah, I was using jsonp, which doesn't return a xhr object. The problem I'm having now is that the progress callback only fires once when it is done.

Comment: That's for another question :D